# how to create a transition probability matrix inside the transition probability matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, probability, markov

I am a beginner in Matlab.I have to create a 3D matrix using markov chain based approach.
In order to understand my question, I request you to see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9dqc.jpg) first.
This approach has a table of the big 3D matrix with velocity and acceleration (i.e different state of velocity and acceleration).Each cell in the table has 2*2probability matrix. In each cell of transition probability matrix, the probability matrix of the velocity and the acceleration at the next time tk+1 are included.This probability matrix should have different acceleration state say like -0.5,0,0.5m/s^2 and velocity of 5,10,15 m/s, the values should be made parametric so that I can later decide to change it later.Then I should populate the matrix with a probability value, but before that, I want to know how to build this matrix.My question is how to build this 4 by 4 matrix .Can someone please suggest me how should I build this velocity and acceleration table which includes in-build 2 *2 matrix table in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but I would suggest using a cell array to store your transition matrix and than a normal matrix inside the transition matrix to store your probability matrices.

Create your transition matrix like so

```
transition = cell(4,4);
```

Add a probability matrix

```
transition{1,1} = [0.25, 0.25; 0.25, 0.25];
```

To easily access to correct entries given your parameters you can create
an index map.

```
index_map_a = -0.5:0.5:0.5;
index_map_v = 0:1:92;
transition(index_map_v == 40, index_map_a == 0.5)
```